Implementing UWB communications in an OMNeT++ project
I am new to using OMNeT++. I want to create a project to implement UWB communications between UWB devices and UWB anchors using OMNeT++ 6.1 and INET 4.5.4.
Here are the files I have created for the project:

UWBNetwork.ned:

package uwb1;

import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;
import inet.physicallayer.wireless.common.contract.packetlevel.IRadioMedium;
import inet.physicallayer.wireless.common.medium.RadioMedium;
import inet.mobility.single.RandomWaypointMobility;

network UWBNetwork

{
    parameters:

        int numNodes = default(5);

    submodules:

        radioMedium: RadioMedium {

            @display("p=100,100");

        }

        node[numNodes]: StandardHost {

            @display("p=200+100*i,200");

            mobility.typename = "RandomWaypointMobility";

            @children:

            wlan[0].radio.transmitter.typename = "UWBTransmitter";

            wlan[0].radio.receiver.typename = "UWBReceiver";

        }

    connections allowunconnected:

        for i=0..numNodes-1 {
            
            node[i].wlan[0] <--> radioMedium <--> node[(i+1) % numNodes].wlan[0];           
        }
}


UWBTransmitter.cc:

#include <omnetpp.h>
#include "inet/applications/base/ApplicationBase.h"
#include "inet/common/packet/Packet.h"

using namespace omnetpp;

using namespace inet;

class UWBTransmitter : public ApplicationBase

{

protected:

virtual void initialize(int stage) override;

virtual void handleMessageWhenUp(cMessage *msg) override;

void sendUWBMessage();

void handleUWBMessage(cPacket *pkt);

cMessage *sendEvent = nullptr;

};

Define_Module(UWBTransmitter);

void UWBTransmitter::initialize(int stage)

{

ApplicationBase::initialize(stage);

if (stage == INITSTAGE_LOCAL) {

sendEvent = new cMessage("sendUWBMessage");

scheduleAt(simTime() + par("startTime"), sendEvent);

}

}

void UWBTransmitter::handleMessageWhenUp(cMessage *msg)

{

if (msg == sendEvent) {

sendUWBMessage();

scheduleAt(simTime() + par("sendInterval"), sendEvent);

} else {

cPacket *pkt = check_and_cast<cPacket *>(msg);

handleUWBMessage(pkt);

}

}

void UWBTransmitter::sendUWBMessage()

{

// Create and send a UWB message to the next node

EV << "Sending UWB message" << endl;

Packet *pkt = new Packet("UWBMessage");

pkt->setByteLength(par("messageSize"));

send(pkt, "lowerLayerOut");

}

void UWBTransmitter::handleUWBMessage(cPacket *pkt)

{

// Handle received UWB message

EV << "Received UWB message: " << pkt->getName() << endl;

delete pkt;

}


UWBReceiver.cc:

#include <omnetpp.h>
#include "inet/applications/base/ApplicationBase.h"
#include "inet/common/packet/Packet.h"

using namespace omnetpp;

using namespace inet;

class UWBReceiver : public ApplicationBase

{

protected:

virtual void initialize(int stage) override;

virtual void handleMessageWhenUp(cMessage *msg) override;

void handleUWBMessage(cPacket *pkt);

};

Define_Module(UWBReceiver);

void UWBReceiver::initialize(int stage)

{

ApplicationBase::initialize(stage);

}

void UWBReceiver::handleMessageWhenUp(cMessage *msg)

{

if (msg->isSelfMessage()) {

delete msg;

} else {

cPacket *pkt = check_and_cast<cPacket *>(msg);

handleUWBMessage(pkt);

}

}

void UWBReceiver::handleUWBMessage(cPacket *pkt)

{

// Handle received UWB message

EV << "Received UWB message: " << pkt->getName() << endl;

delete pkt;

}


omnetpp.ini:

[General]
network = UWBNetwork

sim-time-limit = 100s

# Mobility

**.node[*].mobility.bounds = "0,0,1000,1000"

# UWB application parameters

**.node[*].udpApp.startTime = uniform(0s, 10s)

**.node[*].udpApp.sendInterval = exponential(1s)

**.node[*].udpApp.messageSize = 256B

**.node[*].udpApp.localPort = 1000

**.node[*].udpApp.destPort = 2000

However, I encountered the following errors in the "UWBNetwork.ned" file:

" syntax error, unexpected NAME, expecting ';' " at the instruction " wlan[0].radio.transmitter.typename = "UWBTransmitter"; "
" Multiple markers at this line

wrong source gate: submodule 'node' has no gate named 'wlan'
wrong destination gate: submodule 'node' has no gate named 'wlan'
'radioMedium': no such channel type
1 changed line, 2 deleted "



at the instruction " node[i].wlan[0] <--> radioMedium <--> node[(i+1) % numNodes].wlan[0]; "
I want to test the simulations and then extend the project to use it in a localization approach.
